# Como determinar se um ponto de um componente swing está visível na tela?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Como faço para determinar se um determinado ponto *X* dentro de um componente swing está visível na tela do usuário?

Por exemplo, vamos supor que o `JComponent` *A* foi acrescentado a uma janela *B* (normalmente, mas não necessariamente, um `JFrame`).

- Utilizar o método `isVisible()` é fácil. Se isso for falso, então o componente não está visível e com isso nem o ponto *X* dentro dele. O mesmo vale para a janela *B*.
- Se a janela *B* está minimizada, então o componente *A* não está visível e nem o ponto *X* dentro dele.
- Caso o componente *A* esteja dentro de uma hierarquia de containers aonde um deles não está visível, então o componente não está visível.
- Caso o componente *A* esteja além dos limites do seu container, então obviamente ele não está visível.
- Se o componente *A* estiver parcialmente fora do container, eu posso sem dificuldade computar o retângulo de intersecção entre o componente e os seus containers para saber se o ponto *X* encontra-se dentro do container.
- Caso a janela *B* tenha sido arrastada de modo a ficar parcialmente fora da tela, eu consigo usar a classe `Toolkit` do AWT para pegar quais são as áreas do(s) monitor(es) do usuário e então utilizar isso como parte da intersecção de retângulos.
- Dentro da janela *B*, pode haver um outro componente *D* que se sobrepõe ao componente *A* escondendo-o em todo ou em parte. Isso eu posso resolver listando todos os componentes de cada janela e verificando o *z-order*.

Até aqui tudo bem, eu sei que é possível. Mas há mais uma questão que não consigo resolver:

- A janela *B* pode estar parcialmente ou totalmente escondida devido a uma outra janela *C* de uma outra aplicação que esteja por cima, possivelmente escondendo em todo ou em parte o componente *A*.

Esse último item, eu não sei como fazer. Alguém tem uma ideia?

Ah sim, por fim, vamos ignorar que algumas janelas ou componentes podem ter áreas transparentes ou translúcidas que possam mostrar o conteúdo de outras janelas ou componentes que estejam por baixo. Vamos considerar que todas as janelas e componentes são retângulos totalmente opacos.

---

Tentei meter a mão na massa e cheguei a isto daqui:

**PointVisibility.java**

```java
package pixelvisibletest;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class PointVisibility {

    private PointVisibility() {
    }

    public static boolean isPointVisibleInComponent(Component c, Point componentLocation) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(c);
        Objects.requireNonNull(componentLocation);
        Point p;
        try {
            p = c.getLocationOnScreen();
        } catch (IllegalComponentStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
        p.x += componentLocation.x;
        p.y += componentLocation.y;
        return isScreenPointVisibleInComponent(c, p);
    }

    public static boolean isScreenPointVisibleInComponent(Component c, Point screenLocation) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(c);
        Objects.requireNonNull(screenLocation);
        Component d = findComponentInScreenLocation(screenLocation);
        while (d != null) {
            if (d == c) return true;
            d = d.getParent();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Component findComponentInScreenLocation(Point screenLocation) {
        if (screenLocation == null) return null;
        return findComponentInScreenLocation(screenLocation, findWindowInScreenLocation(screenLocation));
    }

    public static Window findWindowInScreenLocation(Point screenLocation) {
        if (screenLocation == null) return null;
        // BUG Não consegue determinar se o ponto screenLocation está ou não obscurecido por outra janela.
        for (Window window : Window.getWindows()) {
            Point compCoords;
            try {
                compCoords = window.getLocationOnScreen();
            } catch (IllegalComponentStateException e) {
                continue;
            }
            Point relativeToWindow = new Point(screenLocation.x - compCoords.x, screenLocation.y - compCoords.y);
            Component inTheSameWindow = window.findComponentAt(relativeToWindow.x, relativeToWindow.y);
            if (inTheSameWindow != null) return window;
        }

        return null;
    }

    static Component findComponentInScreenLocation(Point screenLocation, Window window) {
        if (window == null) return null;
        Point copy = (Point) screenLocation.clone();
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(copy, window);
        return SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(window, copy.x, copy.y);
    }
}
```

**MouseVisibility.java**

```java
package pixelvisibletest;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class MouseVisibility {

    private MouseVisibility() {
    }

    public static boolean isComponentUnderMouse(Component c) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(c);
        Component d = findComponentUnderMouse();
        while (d != null) {
            if (d == c) return true;
            d = d.getParent();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Component findComponentUnderMouse() {
        return PointVisibility.findComponentInScreenLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(), findWindowUnderMouse());
    }

    public static Window findWindowUnderMouse() {
        for (Window window : Window.getWindows()) {
            if (window.getMousePosition(true) != null) return window;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Para testar as duas classes acima, criei esta classe:

**PixelVisibleTest.java**

```java
package pixelvisibletest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class PixelVisibleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(PixelVisibleTest::go);
    }

    private static void go() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("teste");
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setSize(400, 100);

        JComponent b = new JComponent() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawRect(5, 5, 3, 3);
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.drawRect(6, 6, 1, 1);
            }
        };
        jf.add(b);
        b.setBounds(15, 15, 20, 20);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setResizable(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (jf.isVisible()) {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                        Point mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                        boolean r1 = jf == MouseVisibility.findWindowUnderMouse();
                        boolean r2 = b == MouseVisibility.findComponentUnderMouse();
                        boolean r3 = MouseVisibility.isComponentUnderMouse(b);
                        boolean r4 = PointVisibility.isPointVisibleInComponent(b, new Point(6, 6));
                        boolean r5 = PointVisibility.isScreenPointVisibleInComponent(b, mouse);
                        boolean r6 = jf == PointVisibility.findWindowInScreenLocation(mouse);
                        boolean r7 = b == PointVisibility.findComponentInScreenLocation(mouse);
                        jf.setTitle("teste " + sn(r1) + sn(r2) + sn(r3) + sn(r4) + sn(r5) + sn(r6) + sn(r7));
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Deixa a thread morrer.
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    private static String sn(boolean b) {
        return b ? "S" : "N";
    }
}
```

O método `findComponentUnderMouse()` da classe `MouseVisibility` determina qual componente é o que se apresenta sob a posição aonde o mouse está. O método `isComponentUnderMouse(Component)` testa se um dado componente é o componente que está debaixo do mouse. **Estes métodos funcionam de forma adequada.**

Ocorre que nem sempre o ponto de referência que me importa é a posição do mouse. Pode ser alguma outra posição arbitrária na tela. Para estes casos eu criei os métodos `findComponentInScreenLocation(Point)` e `isScreenPointVisibleInComponent(Component, Point)` na classe `PointVisibility`. Estes métodos são análogos aos dois métodos que citei acima da classe `MouseVisibility` com a exceção de que o ponto de referência tomado não é a posição do mouse. **Estes métodos NÃO funcionam de forma adequada.**

Na classe de teste, dentro da thread, sete condições são testadas, cada uma referente a um método das classes `PointVisibility` e `MouseVisibility`. O resultado de cada teste é um `boolean` que é mostrado no título da janela (S = sim = verdadeiro, N = não = falso). Ao rodar esta classe (método `main`), basta você arrastar a janela para qualquer lugar e sair movendo o mouse para testar o funcionamento. O ponto `(6, 6)` corresponde ao pixel verde desenhado na tela dentro do quadradinho vermelho.

Os métodos da classe `PointVisibility` estão falhando quando o pixel de referência está sobre o componente, mas tal pixel está encoberto pela janela de uma outra aplicação. O código da classe `PointVisibility` não é capaz de perceber a existência de janelas de outras aplicações. Isso não ocorre com a classe `MouseVisibility` porque nas profundezas do AWT, o método `getMousePosition(boolean)` acaba realizando uma chamada ao método `isWindowUnderMouse(Window)` da interface `java.awt.peer.MouseInfoPeer`. A implementação desta interface é interna, específica de cada JVM e/ou SO, e normalmente feita em código nativo, então não dá simplesmente para imitar usando um ponto arbitrário qualquer ao invés da posição do mouse.

O meu objetivo é ter uma implementação da classe `PointVisibility` que seja capaz de perceber quando o ponto de referência está obscurecido por alguma janela de outra aplicação. Não preciso muito da classe `MouseVisibility`, só coloquei ela aqui para servir de comparativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço nenhuma solução utilizando somente Java, mas sei que é possível fazer isso utilizando a API do Windows, e acredito que também seja possível fazer isso em vários outros toolkits (GTK+, Qt, KDE, etc...) utilizando funções similares as da API do Windows.

No Windows você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

1. Utilize a função [GetDesktopWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para obter o handle do desktop;
2. Utilize a função [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) com o parâmetro GW_HWNDFIRST para obter o handle da janela mais ao topo;
3. Utilize a função [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para obter as coordenadas do retângulo do handle da janela;
4. Utilize a função [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) com o parâmetro GW_HWNDNEXT para obter o handle da próxima janela;
5. Repita os passos 3 e 4 até chegar na sua janela;
6. Utilize os dados que você obteve das outras janelas para calcular quais partes da sua janela estão visíveis (não esqueça de observar a ordem das janelas);
7. Calcule se o ponto que você quer conferir está em uma das partes da janela que está visível;

Comment: Eu tinha medo de que a resposta fosse algo assim. Ou seja, a saída é usar JNI ou algo parecido e escrever código independente para cada sistema operacional mais ou menos como você descreveu...

Comment: Infelizmente sim...